# combine array elements and send response

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

This is my request body which I am sending on click of form submit button:

```
{ 
    "name":'test', 
    "age":'test1', 
    "appId":[10,20,30], 
    "dataId":[1,2,3] 
}
```

I want to modify it this this:

```
[
    { name: "test", age: "test1", appId: 10, dataId: 1 },
    { name: "test", age: "test1", appId: 10, dataId: 2 },
    { name: "test", age: "test1", appId: 10, dataId: 3 },
    { name: "test", age: "test1", appId: 20, dataId: 1 },
    { name: "test", age: "test1", appId: 20, dataId: 2 },
    { name: "test", age: "test1", appId: 20, dataId: 3 },
]
```

This needs to be done using Javascript (ES6).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try using two for loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Cartesian product:

```js
const cartesian = (a, b) => a.flatMap(appid => b.map(dataid => ({appid, dataid})));

console.log(cartesian(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3]));
```

In a comment below you provide an object wrapper around the two input arrays, and want the other object properties to be copied into the result objects.

So then it becomes:

```js
const cartesian = (obj, a, b) => 
    obj[a].flatMap(x => obj[b].map(y => ({...obj, [a]: x, [b]: y}) ));


const response = {name:'test', age:'test1', appId:[10,20,30], dataId:[1,2,3]};
const result = cartesian(response, "appId", "dataId");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let combinedArray = [];
array1.forEach((element, index) => {
    let batch = [];
    array2.forEach((element2, index2) => {
         batch.push({
              appid: element,
              dataid: element2
         });
    });
    combinedArray.push(...batch);
});
```

Something along these lines.
Seems like the easiest way to do this assuming arrays are the same length and in the right order. You can use for loop instead.

**Actually, that doesn't seem like the right solution either. I'm not sure what pattern you are trying to achieve with your example, so I will leave it like this. You can adjust the algorithm to your needs.**

Edited because I re-read the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
[].concat.apply([],[1,2,3].map(x => [1,2,3].map(y=> { return {'a': x, 'b':y}})))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Const arr1 = [a1, a2, a3];
Const arr2 =[d1, d2, d3];
Const arr3 = [];

for(let i = 0;i<arr1.length;i++){
  for(let b=0;b<arr2.length;b++){
   return arr3.push({appid: arr1[i], dataid: arr2[b] })
}
}
```